# Mongodb C# filter using LINQ

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, filter

I have to filter my mongodb collection on the basis of 3 values.
My class structure is

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public object _id { get; set; } //MongoDb uses this field as identity.
        public Root root { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Row[] row { get; set; }
    }

    public class Row
    {

        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string MarketProfileID { get; set; }     
        public string CodeDetails { get; set; }
        public string OfferTypeID { get; set; }

    }
```

I have to apply the filter in mongo db :

```
var obj = Query.And(
                    Query<Rootobject>.EQ((c => c.root.row.MarketProfileID, marketProfileID.ToString())
                    Query<Rootobject>.EQ(c => c.root.row.CodeDetails, code),
                    Query<Rootobject>.EQ(c => c.root.row.PrivacyLevelID, customerTypeID.ToString())
                  );

List<Rootobject> obj = objDatabse.GetCollection<Rootobject>("Offer").Find(obj ).ToList();
```

But it is not compiling.
Please assist

Offer is a mongodb Collection

Comment: could you show the compiler error? to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: since row class  is an array , there is a flaw in my filter query c => c.root.row.MarketProfileID

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: 'Row[]' does not contain a definition for 'CodeDetails' and no extension method 'CodeDetails' accepting a first argument of type 'Row[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use LINQ syntax here.
Please try this:

```
            IMongoCollection<Rootobject> rootCollection = rootsDatabase.GetCollection<Rootobject>("Offer");
        var roots = rootCollection.Find<Rootobject>(r => r.root.row.Any(
            row => row.MarketProfileID == "somevalue" &&
            row.CodeDetails == "somevalue")).ToList();
```

Your row class doesn't have PrivacyLevelID, so it would not compile anyways, but I hope you got the idea.